# MVVM WPF: Why is the property in the Model always null even after updating the text in textbox while running the application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, textbox

I gave up on MVP pattern and gave MVVM and WPF a try. I managed so far to navigate the menu showing different UserControls by clicking different buttons. DataBinding and Commands are working fine for navigation however i ran into a problem when DataBinding a textbox.

The property always get the value null and i do not know why. I added a command to get the UserID from a textbox when clicking a button and to show a MessageBox containing the UserID just to make it simple before i try anything else.

The MessageBox shows but it is empty. I added a Task.Run in the UsersModel.cs so i can see if the string updates on propertychange but value is null.

I am using a class for ObservableObject to notify OnPropertyChanged. And a RelayCommand class that inherits from ICommand. Both seems to work as intended but only when clicking the buttons to show different UserControls and Close the application. Below is sample code from View, Model and ViewModel. What am i missing?

**RegisterMenu.xaml**

```
      <TextBox x:Name="RegTextUserID" Margin="163,66,148,112"
               Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=UserBox}"
               Text="{Binding UserID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                     
           <TextBox.DataContext>
               <models:UsersModel/>
           </TextBox.DataContext>
       </TextBox>

       <Button x:Name="Button_Register" Content="Register" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Margin="183,129,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Command="{Binding Path=GetUserCommand}">
                    
            <Button.DataContext>
               <viewmodels:RegisterViewModel/>
            </Button.DataContext>
        </Button>
```

**UsersModel.cs**

```
 public class UsersModel : ObservableObject
{

    // backing fields
    private string _userID;

    // Properties
    public string UserID      // UserID is null
    {
        get { return _userID; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _userID, value);
        }
    }
    

    // testing loop for propertychange trigger
    public UsersModel()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"UserID:   {UserID}");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

**RegisterViewModel.cs**

```
public class RegisterViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public RelayCommand GetUserCommand { get; set; }

    public RegisterViewModel()
    {
        
        GetUserCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
        {

         // Command is responding to button click.

        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**
Updated the code in UsersModel.cs were i changed ObservableObject.cs to use *[CallerMemberName]* and *SetProperty*. I also removed the *GetUserCommand* code from *RegisterViewModel.cs* so i can only test the property in *UsersModel.cs*.

From what i understand is that the textBox binding is not working. I do not get any value even after using *SetProperty* method.

**EDIT 2**

To clarify, i used the following in XAML earlier (One DataContext) at the start. But i still had the same problem. The UsersModel property is not getting the text i type in the textbox.

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <models: UserModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

I created a sample project with one textbox to try out setting a specific DataContext for the textbox like the code below. It is working in the sample. The output prints the text i write in the textbox. Why is it not working in the UsersModel.cs above?

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="249,60,0,0" 
         Text=" {Binding SomeText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                 Mode=TwoWay}" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
        <TextBox.DataContext>
            <local:TestModel/>
        </TextBox.DataContext>
 </TextBox>
```

**TestModel.cs** (this works, i can see the loop output everytime i change the text in the textbox).

```
class TestModel
 {
    private string _someText;

    public string SomeText
    {
        get { return _someText; }
        set { _someText = value; }
    }

    public TestModel()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(SomeText);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation for the ObservableObject shows you need to call the SetProperty() method on it to raise the notification events. [ObservableObject](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject#simple-property). _"The provided SetProperty<T>(ref T, T, string) method checks the current value of the property, and updates it if different, and then also raises the relevant events automatically. The property name is automatically captured through the use of the [CallerMemberName] attribute, so there's no need to manually specify which property is being updated."_

Comment: `UsersModel User = new()` creates a new UsersModel, totally unrelated to the UsersModel used as DataContext for the TextBox

Comment: @quaabaam I had the same problem even with SetProperty and the use of [CallerMemberName]. But i will adjust my code and try again.

Comment: @KlausGütter What about in the UsersModel.cs, shouldn't the loop keep changing the UserID everytime i update the textbox because i set the UpdateSourceTrigger to propertychange?

Comment: I don't understand the 2 contexts used here. I usually set a context to the form/dialog and use the properties from there. Second thing is that binding mode can be set to `TwoWay` which ensures that the view can write back, Not sure.

Comment: @AlexanderSchmidt I had one DataContext earlier because i was using the property in the viewmodel. But after using the model for property to seperate the viewmodel and model, ie to let the viewmodel handle the commands and show data from the model. So i set a datacontext for the textbox to bind the property from the model and another for the button to bind the command from the viewmodel. Not sure if this is the correct way either.

Comment: You don't just declare new instances of your DataContext in XAML.  You inherit them through the visual/logical tree.  You can inherit them from the parent control/window in which your window/button appears.  If your button is part of a DataTemplate, than your datacontext is the DataType of the DataTemplate.   But simply declaring a new instance in XAML or in code-behind does nothing

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the error in the wrong place. I managed to locate the error to the Style. I've tested to remove the style and the binding worked fine. I have to adjust the code of the Themes i am using. Thanks for all the comments.